# Unable to obtain the locales file content when using multiple files for same language in Vue 3 using vueI18n and intlify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I am trying to use locale files in my Nuxt 3-based application and everything works fine when I am using the single `en.yml` file but if I try to add another file for the same language then the contents from that new file are not extracted only the main file works fine. I am using the `intlify` and `vueI18n` for internationalization.

I have a `locales/en` folder which contains the locale files `en.yml` and `en-extended.yml`. I would like to obtain the content into my Nu 3 application but am unable to do so using the vue18n for `en-extended.yml` file content but `en.yml` file content works fine.

Following is the config settings from `nuxt.config.js`:

```
intlify: {
    localeDir: "../locales",
    vueI18n: {
      locale: "en", // Set the default locale
      fallbackLocale: "en",
    },
  },
```

I tried adding additional parameters to it using the `en-extended` but its not working. I have placed the file and variables are present but still not working.

Following is the way I am accessing the date:

```
<div class="text-primary">
    <!-- Access common translation from en.yml -->
    <p>{{ $t("default.mainMessage") }}</p>

    <!-- Access translation from en-extended.yml using the en_extended namespace -->
    <p>{{ $t("en-extended.default.extendedMessage") }}</p>
  </div>
```

I can see on my webpage that I am able to get: `"default.mainMessage"` but unable to get the `"en-extended.default.extendedMessage"` It just displays the same variable name `en-extended.default.extendedMessage` rather than the actual value assigned in `en-extended.yml`